# PHP process (started by the PHP-Java bridge) getting terminated unexpectedly

Tags: java, php, tomcat

I have an application running in **Tomcat 6.0.36**. There was a requirement to implement CMS (content management) in our application. For this, a third party vendor is signed up to provide the static content. The CMS pages are written in PHP and hence it became necessary for us to render the PHP content using tomcat server.

To achieve this, I downloaded the “**JavaBridgeTemplate621.war**” (from http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_6.2.1/JavaBridgeTemplate621.war/download) and deployed it in the webapps folder. Later I renamed the exploded folder and renamed it to ‘cms’ (deleted the JavaBridgeTemplate621.war file this time). The PHP files placed in this ‘**webapps/cms**’ folder is rendered properly by the tomcat server. This was the exact requirement.

While starting the tomcat server, the PHP-Java bridge also created a few Java processes. On the LIVE environment, these processes were killed 3-4 days after the deployment(restart) happened.

The error in the catalina log is,

*PHP application terminated unexpectedly, have you started php-cgi with the environment setting PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000?  Error: php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionException
php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionException
at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionOutputStream.flush(FCGIConnectionOutputStream.java:87)
at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionOutputStream.close(FCGIConnectionOutputStream.java:71)
at php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.parseBody(FastCGIServlet.java:357)*

Can someone help me understand the root cause of this issue?

The ‘**memory_limit**’ variable is seen to have the value **64M**. Is it too low a value ? If so, what would be an ideal value that needs to be set ?

How will the setting ‘**expose_php=off**’ affect ?